Oracle Apex "Error processing request. Contact your application administrator"
Suddenly, my Oracle Apex workspace started gives error.
see the image
I reinstalled ORDS, unlocked all the users like below;
Nothing worked, i still get the error
alter user APEX_PUBLIC_USER identified by oracle account unlock;
alter user APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER identified by oracle account unlock;
alter user APEX_LISTENER identified by oracle account unlock;
alter user TEST_SCHEMA identified by oracle account unlock;
alter user WKSP_ILA identified by oracle account unlock;
alter user ORDS_PUBLIC_USER identified by oracle account unlock;


